# nginx location block speed

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

Is there way to test/measure/know speed of locations block below?

```
location ~* (^/block1/|^block2|block3|...^blockN) { }
```

and

```
location /block1 {} 
location /block2 {}
location /block3 {}
...
location /blockN {}
```

Will speed of traversing this block be same or different and why?

Comment: What is `location ^/block1`? Do you mean `location ~ ^/block1` or `location /block1`?

Comment: Nginx manages prefix locations very efficiently and should always be preferred to regular expressions if you have a choice.

Comment: Thanks you for comment. I have same belief. Pity that it can be proved in some obvious way.